# servidor escuchando pero no anda en navegador - Node js

Tags: nodejs

Hola gente estoy empezando con node js siguiendo tutoriales, resulta que tengo el siguiente código:

```
'use strict'
 const express = require('express');
 const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

 const app= express();

 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}))
 app.use((bodyParser.json));
 //cuando le hago una peticion a node
 //req= peticion , res= respuesta
 app.get('/', (req,res)=>{

    res.send({message:'Directorio raiz'});
});
 app.get('/hola', (req,res)=>{

console.log("asd");
res.send({message:'Hola mundo'});
});
app.listen(8080,()=>{
console.log("Servidor escuchando" );
});
```

Al momento de ejecutarlo el servidor queda "escuchando" pero cuando voy al navegador y abro localhost:8080 nunca da respuesta
que puede ser?? es el mismo código del tutorial, en donde si funciona.

Comment: Esto `app.use((bodyParser.json));` debería ser así `app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Comment: De hecho hasta podrías omitir la instalacion de `body-parser` y simplemente configurarlo con `app.use(express.json())`, siempre y cuando estés usando una versión de Express 4.16.0 o superior.